# Editing Sorted Column Values in DataGridView

Tags: c#, sorting, datagridview, edit

I have a DataGridView which allows the user to set a value in multiple rows simultaneously by first selecting several rows and choosing a value from the context menu.  I acheive this by iterating over all the selected row setting the appropriate column of each row to the values specified.  This works well if the DataGridView is not sorted by the column being modified however if you attempt to modify the values in the sorted column often some of the values end up not being changed.

So if I were to have a table like the following sorted by the 3rd column:

```
x  x  T*  x
x  x  T*  x
x  x  T*  x
x  x  F   x
x  x  F   x
```

And you wanted to set all the values in the third column to "F" you should be able to select the first three rows and set the 3rd column's value to "F" but what I think happens is that as the program iterates over the selected rows they change order and you often end up with:

```
x  x  T*  x
x  x  F*  x
x  x  F*  x
x  x  F   x
x  x  F   x
```

What I think is happening is that the "SelectedRow" list is defined by index and if rows are rearranged while iterating over the "SelectedRows" this results in some rows getting their values set twice while others don't get their value set at all.  Is it possible to suspend reordering till iterating is complete, or is there another way of ensuring each of the selected rows is modified exactly once?

Edit: By the way, setting the columns "SortMode" to "NotSortable" doesn't seem to help.

As in:

```
DataGridViewColumnSortMode temp = dgv[currenttab].Columns["column"].SortMode;
dgv[currenttab].Columns["column"].SortMode = AataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv[currenttab].SelectedRows) {
    row.Cells["column"].Value = "F";
}

dgv[currenttab].Columns["colour"].SortMode = temp;
```

As cumbersome as it is it still has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm not allowed to comment yet, but have you tried looping through the indexes of the SelectedRows collection yet?  By explicitly referencing the index, the order in which the row appears in the SelectedRows collection should no longer matter.

For example,

```
for (int index = 0; index < SelectedRows.Count; index ++)
{
    SelectedRows.SelectedRow[index].column[column] = newValue;
 }
```

Comment: I havn't tried that, however I can't see it working.

I believe the problem is that when you change the value of the 'sort by' column the rows end up changing their 'index'.  So, when you change the value of row '1' it becomes row '4' (such that it ends up being written to a second time later in the list) and a different (unmodified) row gets pushed into index 1 which is how rows end up slipping through.

I will however give it a go and will be pleasantly surprised if it works ;)

Comment: Okay, just tried it and alas no, if anything it is even worse :cry-sad:

Answer (score 0):

I see, sorry about that:(  One other idea I had to fix it with brute force is adding a counter variable, something like this:

```
Do until (x == SelectedRows.Count)
{   
for each(DataGridViewRow row in dgv[currenttab].SelectedRows)     
{
if(row.Cells["column"].Value != newValue)
{
row.Cells["column"].Value == newValue;
x+=1;
}
```

This way, everytime a change is made you keep track of it in the counter variable, and then you keep repeating the action until each selected row has been changed.

Comment: I tried something similar to that and it almost worked.

One problem with the implementation above is that not all the rows necessarily need to be modified (as you could select some rows that happen to have the desired value already and therefore do not need to be changed) in which case it would get stuck in the loop for ever.

Comment: The 'brute force' method I employed was to loop over all the selected rows and just note if any changes were made.  If any rows were modified than it would loop over them all again, and again till it managed to loop over all rows without making any modifications.  However, even this horribly hacky approach doesn't quite work!  As a test I selected all but the first row and was disappointed to see that all the rows ended up being modified.

Comment: I suspect what happened is that after one of the rows is modified it is rearranged into the 'first' position and the unselected row (which was in the first position) gets moved into the selection and ends up getting modified on one of the 'bruit force' re-loops.

I can't believe this is so difficult.  I honestly thought it was going to be a really simple thing.

Comment: I see your predicament! Well, it ain't pretty, but I guess you could first loop through the selected Items and count how many selected records need to be changed.  Then compare x to that counter. This would result in 2 loops.                                                                                                                 i.e.     Do until (x == numRecordsToChange)

Answer (score 0):

I have had a very similar problem using C#. I have found two things that should help. First, this loop:

```
Do until (x == SelectedRows.Count)
{   
  for each(DataGridViewRow row in dgv[currenttab].SelectedRows)     
  {
    if(row.Cells["column"].Value != newValue)
    {
      row.Cells["column"].Value == newValue;
      x+=1;
    }
```

Does not work reliably because the instant you set the sorted column to a new value it can move to its new position in the grid, and the `SelectedRows` collection becomes essentially corrupted. If you fix that, e.g. by iterating in reverse index order if you know that the modification might move one or more of the rows later in the table, you still get a problem because Selected rows do not sort properly when you programmatically change the sort key; some of the rows move to the correct new position, some don't!

I came across this post on MSDN:
[Selected Row in DataGridView is not properly sorted](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/76bf22aa-7ef1-430d-b1eb-266f6f31851d).

Amro's response in the post suggests setting DataGridView's CurrentCell property outside the selection. To make this work I had to do a bit more:

1. Set `CurrentCell` somewhere outside `SelectedRows`.
2. Modify the rows. Now the new values are correctly applied to the right row, *but* one of the rows appears in the wrong place in the grid.
3. To fix this iterate through all rows setting any one of their cells current.
4. Re-select the row(s) that the user still expects to be selected after they have moved.

What a palaver!